# Taking the derivative of a quadratic form

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Consider the following expression:

$$l(a) = \|y\|_2^2 -2y^TXa + a^TX^TX a$$

where $X$ is some matrix. The derivative is

$$\nabla l(a) = 2X^TXa -2X^T y$$

I'm new to matrix calculus. Could you please explain how to get the derivative?

Comment: I would suggest that you write the expression down in components. Then the result should be pretty "obvious".

Comment: Well yeah, I guess it's feasible. I just wanted to set up my mind on matrix-calculus and understand how to do it quickly, in an higher level.

Comment: Let $w=(Xa-y)$ and let colon denote the dot product. Then we have $$\eqalign{l&=w:w\cr dl&=2w:dw=2w:X\,da=2X^Tw:da\cr\nabla l&=2X^Tw=2X^T(Xa-y)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to prove this using index notation for each component, but it sounds like you want a more intuitive explanation.

The first term is constant so its differential is zero. The second term is a linear function of $a$, so its differential is given by the same matrix: $2y^TX$.

The last term is equal to $Xa\cdot Xa=||Xa||^2$, where the dot represents the dot product. This is the composition of two functions, first matrix multiplication by $X$, then the function $v\to||v||^2=\sum v_i^2$; the first of these of course has differential $X$, and the second has differential $(2v_1,\dots,2v_n)=2v^T$. Using the chain rule this becomes $2(Xa)^TX=2a^TX^TX$.

Putting this together we have

$\nabla l(a) = 2a^TX^TX -2y^TX$.

Taking the transpose of this yields your expression.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by [differential rules for matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities)

$$\frac{\partial u^TAv}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}Av+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}A^Tu$$

thus

$$\frac{\partial(y^TXa)}{\partial a}=X^Ty$$

$$\frac{\partial(a^TX^TXa)}{\partial a}=X^TXa+X^TXa=2X^TXa$$

Answer (score 0):

**Some hints**

1. I assume that vectors have $N$ entries, and matrices are $N \times N$.
   Then, you are taking the derivative with respect to $N$ variables. **This means that you must obtain a vector of $N$ derivatives as a results**. Each entry of this vector is the derivative with respect to one entry of the vector $a$.
2. When dealing with vectors, matrices and the standard vector-vector/vector-matrix/matrix-matrix product, then you obtain expressions where **only additions and multiplications appear**.
3. Consider the case $v^\top a$, where $v$ is a vector (notice that you can pose $v = 2Xy$ in the term $-2y^\top X a$ in your example). It is easy to see that the derivative with respect to $a_i$ is simply $v_i$. **Then, which is the vector representing the derivative of this term?**
4. Consider now the more complex case $v(a)^\top v(a)$ (notice that you can pose $v(a) = Xa$ in the term $a^\top X^\top X a$ in your example). Using the rule of product, you have that the derivative with respect to $a_i$ is:
   $$v_i(a) + v_i(a) = 2v_i(a).$$
   **Then, which is the vector representing the derivative of this term?**

Comment: Thank you for those hints!